# Async/Await with .NET Framework 4.0 & Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, async-await

I am trying to use Async/Await in VS2013Community/Framework 4.0/Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

I tried everything and I just can't get it working.
I am always getting *Expression is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)', which is not awaitable.* bullshit no matter what I do.

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Start()
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
  Private Async Sub Start()
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for long operation completing...")
    Dim n = Await GetNumber()
    Console.WriteLine("Long operation completed.")
  End Sub
  Private Async Function GetNumber() As Task(Of Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Long operation starting...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Return 1
  End Function
End Module
```

This does not work in Framework 4.0 + Microsoft.Bcl.Async, but works in Framework 4.5. I can not use 4.5 because of Windows XP on client computers.

Comment: Its clearly not supported in frameworks under 4.5 ... you answered your own question.

Comment: If not, then what is purpose of Microsoft.Bcl.Async??? I thought that this package exists to support Async/Await in 4.0.

Comment: @Ondřej you didn't misunderstand, the package does add async/await support to .NET 4.0 projects. In fact, your error message shows that the compiler *understands* awaiting. Any chance your project has the wrong references, eg 2.0 dlls or one of the libraries used to emulate tasks in 3.5?

Comment: @Ondřej you may want to search SO for similar questions. In many cases, switching frameworks in a project doesn't remove all old references. In another cases the problem is caused by libraries that emulate the TPL in .NET 3.5, which have similar names and namespaces as the .NET 4.0 classes

Comment: VS2013Community Update 5: I created new .NET Framework 4 Console Application VB.NET project. I added Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package and code above. Not working, same error message at compile time.

Comment: No repro on a new .NET 4 console project on VS 2015. Do you have references to both System.Threading.Tasks and Microsoft.Threading.Tasks? There should be 3 references to Microsoft.Threading.Tasks,Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions,Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Desktop. Also, Bcl.Async should have installed Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build as well

Comment: Also check the package versions. The latest Bcl.Async is 1.0.168, and its dependencies are Bcl 1.1.8, Bcl.Build 1.0.14. There are newer versions of the dependencies - perhaps a failed upgrade broke your project? Upgrading them though didn't break my test

Comment: Same error _Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>'_ occurs in same C# project.

Comment: Had they broken VB.NET support my test wouldn't work either. Try starting with a clean project that targets 4.0, to eliminate the chance that switching runtimes caused an issue. Also note that when I change the target framework, I get errors that there are references with duplicate definitions. Does the same happen in your case?

Comment: I started new, clean 4.0 project with only Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. When I start new 4.5 project with Microsoft.Bcl.Async package and switch it to 4.0, 5 warnings are shown but build is without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Everything works as expected in Visual Studio 2015. You can enjoy **Async/Await in .NET Framework 4 applications using VS2015, but not VS2013**. Shame on you Microsoft.

Comment: No you don't. Try code that I posted above and it will not work. Rewrite it to C# and it will not work too.